# Can I use CAST() in a select statement?

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, casting

I am trying to use a CAST() in an SQL statement but it doesn't allow me to see the CAST(myDateTime, Date) as myLoginShortDate in the group by?  I only know the basics of SQL and I am trying to learn more.
May data looks like this:

CustomerID int, null
Email varchar(60)
DateEntered DateTime

I am trying to get the a grouping by the date part of the datetime and grouped on the Email

My stored procedure select part looks like this:

```
       select  cll.Email,CAST(cll.DateEntered as Date) as LoginDate, 
              COUNT(cll.email) as FailedCount
            from [GC].[dbo].[CustomerLoginLog] as cll
            where [CustomerId] is null
            group by LoginDate, cll.Email
            order by FailedCount desc`
```

It is returning "Invalid column name 'LoginDate'"

I want to be able to see:

> Email,           LoginDate,            FailedCount
>
> xyz@test.com,     11/01/12,             21
>
> abc@test2.com,    11/01/12,             17
>
> xyz@test.com,     10/30/12,             15

and so on.  I am sure this is just a beginners  mistake.  I have this post all messed up but I hope somebody understands it.  The select format looks better on my computer.

Comment: I see in your comment on Cory's answer you asked about a good book for moving your T-SQL skills to the next level.  I'd highly recommend Itzik Ben-Gan's "T-SQL Fundamentals".  It really helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` statement is evaluated before the `SELECT` statement, so SQL server doesn't know about the alias you gave the expression in the `SELECT` statement. To remedy this, you simply have to repeat the expression in the `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY CAST(cll.DateEntered AS Date)
```

Or wrap the simple part of your query with a CTE, and do the grouping on the CTE results:

```
;WITH MyQuery AS 
(
    SELECT
        cll.Email
        ,CAST(cll.DateEntered AS Date) AS LoginDate
    FROM 
        [GC].[dbo].[CustomerLoginLog] AS cll
    WHERE 
        cll.[CustomerId] IS NULL
)
SELECT 
    Email
    ,LoginDate
    ,COUNT(*) AS FailedCount
FROM 
    MyQuery
GROUP BY 
    LoginDate, Email
ORDER BY 
    FailedCount DESC
```

Alternatively you could include the content of the CTE as in a nested SELECT statement as [Mahmoud pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13423765/74757).

Comment: I get a 'CustomerLoginLog.Email' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.  Can you recommend a good book for someone who has done basic SQL and pushed into the harder stuff?

Comment: @user1830640: That's my fault. I updated my answer to account for my mistake. And no, I guess I don't have any books I could recommend off the top of my head. Check [so] or Amazon for highly rated SQL books!

Comment: Thanks, you got me on the right track.  I moved the "COUNT(cll.email) AS FailedCount" down to the MyQuery Part and put "*, COUNT(MyQuery.email) AS FailedCount" and it works great. Moving from VFP to C#.net and SQL Server 2008 all at once it rough stuff. :)

Comment: @user1830640: Just don't keep the "MyQuery" name! -- rename the CTE to something useful, like "CustomerLoginDetail."

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT` statement is (logically) executed after the `GROUP BY` clause, so that the `GROUP BY` clause can't see that alias `LoginDate`. You have to use kind of subquery, or a CTE like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT 
     cll.Email,
     CAST(cll.DateEntered as Date) as LoginDate, 
     COUNT(cll.email) as FailedCount
   FROM [GC].[dbo].[CustomerLoginLog] as cll
   WHERE [CustomerId] IS NULL
) t
GROUP BY LoginDate, cll.Email
ORDER BY FailedCount DESC
```